# JTextArea with selectable rows

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jcomponent

I'm making an application and I need a JComponent that looks like a JTextArea where I can select individual rows.

I know I could do it by using a JTextArea and managing it myself, but there is probably a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. The thing is I have no idea what to search for on Google because I don't know how such a component is called.

Here is a picture that shows what I want: [image: Example of what I want]

The section with "ADMIN" highlighted is exactly what I'm looking for. From that, I'm going to fill out some informations in other parts of the program, so I need to be able to know what is selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a **[JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)**, not a JTextArea. It has functionality like selection built-in. It can be shown with elements either horizontally or vertically. Please have a look at the official tutorial to which I've linked.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know what to search for.